# How to select data-id in jQuery after the data-id is changed in the page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/V76T7/

```
 $('.click').click(function() {
  id = $(this).data('id');
  alert(id);
  $('.click').attr('data-id' , id+1);
 });
```

As shown in the link, I want the data-id to increase by 1 each time I click the button. The data-id did indeed increase to 2 when you click it and you can see it using 'Inspect Element" in Chrome. But the next time I click on it, the popup is still 1, but not "2" as expected. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `.data` to get the value, it'll be imported into `jQuery.cache`, so future `.data()` fetches will come from there instead of from the attribute.

As such, you need to update using `.data()` if you want the next "get" to fetch the updated value.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    id = $(this).data('id');
    alert(id);
    $('.click').data('id' , id+1);
});
```

---

Or better, just use `.attr()` since it's faster, and has less memory overhead (since the value isn't duplicated in `jQuery.cache`).

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
    $('.click').attr('data-id' , id+1);
});
```

---

I'd suggest only using `.data()` for this if you need to retain the original, or if you're working with more complex objects like those created from a JSON value.

Comment: You must use parseInt(id) to sum instead of concatenate

Comment: @Cyrus: True. Not directly related, but it would need to be fixed to get the `2` result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using the same method for both getting and setting the data attribute (either [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/))
2. Avoid use of implicitly declared global variables by placing `var` in front of `id`.

So your code should look like this:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     alert(id);
     $(this).data('id', id+1);
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/V76T7/2/)